# XNA 3D Skybox simulation issue with camera position and model translation

Tags: 3d, xna

I have create a XNA 4.0 3D project in VS 2015 Community. It has a Skybox with a bullet model which i am trying to simulate the trajectory. I cannot seem to get the camera in the right position and the the translation seem to working in the wrong axis.

I have tried changing the position of the model, camera and even the perspective.

```cs
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Allows the game to exit
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.ButtonState.Pressed)
        this.Exit();

    mDeltaTime = gameTime;
    mFlightTime += 0.1f;


    //if (mAngleInput != 0)
    //{
    //    mVelocity.X = (float)(mVelocityInput * Math.Cos(DegreeToRadian(mAngleInput)));
    //    mVelocity.Y = (float)(mVelocityInput * Math.Sin(DegreeToRadian(mAngleInput)));
    //}

    position = (mStartingPosition + mVelocity * mFlightTime) - (0.5f * mAcceleration * (float)Math.Pow(mFlightTime, 2)) / 5;


    // This updates the world matrix, so that it reflects the changes to the position
    // and angle.  Remember that this matrix determines where the model will be located
    // at in the 3D world.

    //   camTarget += new Vector3(0.1f,0,0);

    //           world = Matrix.CreateRotationY(angle) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(position);
    //            view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(camTarget, position,  Vector3.UnitY);

    cameraPosition =  (distance * new Vector3((float)Math.Sin(angle), 0, (float)Math.Cos(angle)));
    Vector3 cameraTarget = position;
    //original Vector3 cameraTarget = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);

    viewVector = Vector3.Transform(cameraTarget - cameraPosition, Matrix.CreateRotationY(0));
    // viewVector.Normalize();

    angle += 0.002f;

    world = Matrix.CreateScale(0.5f) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(angle) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(position);
    view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraTarget, cameraPosition, Vector3.UnitY);
    //original view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Vector3.UnitY);

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

I was hoping that the model would start in a certain position and move Horizontal X axis and dropping down the Vertical Y Axis based on the trajectory formula i am using. Stopping once it reaches a certain Y value.

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you share the Draw() Method and variable initializations.

Comment: @Strom Game1.cs file is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/wews924zmyqg6rj/Game1.cs?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You are moving the Camera so that it is orbiting the World origin on the XZ Plane in a circle with a radius of `distance` while always looking at the bullet.

To see the bullet movement, the Camera must be in a fixed position and rotation. Assuming the initial bullet position of (0,0,0), your camera needs to be offset on the Z axis to prevent the `LookAt` vector from degenerating to a `NaN`.

You could move the camera to follow the bullet on the X axis, but it would start in the middle of the screen and drop straight down.

```
Protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{

    //mDeltaTime = gameTime;  
    mFlightTime += 0.1f;

    //position = (mStartingPosition + mVelocity * mFlightTime) - (0.5f * mAcceleration * (float)Math.Pow(mFlightTime, 2)) / 5;
    // The previous line can be simplified, assuming you do not need to jump to a specific time:
    position += mVelocity;
    mVelocity +=mAcceleration;
    mAcceleration += mDrag;
    mDrag = -bulletCoefficient * airDensity * mBulletCrossSection * (float)Math.Pow(mVelocity, 2) / 2; 

    cameraTarget = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    cameraPosition = new Vector3(0,0,-1);   

    world = Matrix.CreateScale(0.5f) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(angle) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(position);
    view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraTarget, cameraPosition, Vector3.UnitY);    

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
`
```

Comment: What should the variable types be for mVelocity, mAcceleration and mDrag? Vectors or floats? position is a Vector3. How do i load the model into a specific position?

Comment: @SSHK They are `Vector3`s.  position needs to be set to the starting position.  Each model will use its own world transform matrix.

Comment: Not seeing anything appear on the screen.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention you have to scale your movement(gravity and drag) values by 1/60. You may also have to move the camera back(depending on the field of view).